# Cannot Check Installed Python Version in Windows Command Line

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I an trying to check which version of it I have installed. I remember I installed it a while back, and I do not remember which version I installed back then.

While searching for a way to check my Python version, I came across the following commands that were said to be usable in the Windows command line (I am running Windows 10), so I tried them, but they gave me blank lines as responses and nothing else:

```
python --version
python -V
```

[Response to the previous lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SznDJ.png)

Is there another way I can check my Python version?

Comment: i had this once, and was solved after a restart, cache problems

Comment: You will need to add Python to your PATH.
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Answer (score 0):

```
import platform

print(platform.python_version())
```

This should do the trick (for Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

Run this from your python IDLE

```
import sys
print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to get the Windows command to work, not a way to do it from python itself. Regardless, this was helpful in its own way.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the issue by adding Python to my PATH. The instructions from the following website were very useful: [https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path)